# Separate kafka servers for retry topics and DLT?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

Can we use separate kafka clusters for the main topic and retry topics?
The idea is to not keep a single point of failure which can occur if kafka is down, hence we need 2 different kafka servers, so that if one is down then at least we can pause the consumption for the main one.

I am trying to implement spring kafka non blocking retries as mentioned here https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#retry-topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide separate `KafkaListenerContainerFactory` and `KafkaTemplate` instances configured with different broker settings to be used with with the `RetryTopic` feature.

These will be used for forwarding the message to the retry topics, and for creating the retry topics' containers.

The main topic container will still be created with the factory specified in the `@KafkaListener` annotation, or the factory provided by Spring Boot's autoconfiguration.

Refer to [this part](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#retry-topic-lcf) of the documentation for specifying a different factory for the retry topic containers.

The retry topic `KafkaTemplate` can be specified both in the `@RetryableTopic` annotation or the `RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder`. You can also provide a bean with name `RetryTopicInternalBeanNames.DEFAULT_KAFKA_TEMPLATE_BEAN_NAME` if you're using the annotation.